# Modify Parsing of CEF Logs Collected via OMS Agent

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-sentinel

I followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sentinel/connect-common-event-format documentation to get the logs into the Azure Sentinel workspace. In my event, I have a field called FlexNumber, if the value of that field is an integer, it is getting extracted, but if the value of that field is a floating-point number, the field value is overwritten by null. The logs are ingested into the CommonSecurityLog table.

[image]

Here I want to change the datatype of FlexNumber1 and FlexNumber2 from int to float. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Related question is raised in [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8f156fb1-f704-4937-a386-d1e5574963d6/modify-parsing-of-cef-logs-collected-via-oms-agent?forum=opinsights) MSDN thread; Just sharing this for the benefit of broader audience who might face similar issue.